# VPN from AWS Workspace

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, windows-10

I have recently created a Win10 AWS WorkSpace and I want to connect from there to my public VPN server. I am using the same settings as on my home internet but in AWS the connections times out. Is something network related that prevents the L2TP or PPTP VPN connections. Can I configure or setup additional network settings on AWS? thanks,

Comment: What is the VPN client that you are using? Can you access the VPN logs from your client? Is the Windows firewall blocking? https://www.magnumvpn.com/setup-windows-10-firewall-l2tp.html

Comment: @JohnHanley I've tried also with the firewall turned off but nothing changing. I'm using the native Windows 10 VPN client

Comment: Use the Windows Event Viewer to look for events from RasClient. This may help you. Also look at this document https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/325034/how-to-troubleshoot-a-microsoft-l2tp-ipsec-virtual-private-network-cli

Comment: Also, review your security group settings for WorkSpaces https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workspaces/latest/adminguide/amazon-workspaces-security-groups.html

Comment: @SWE Did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. The issue was the "Amazon WorkSpaces Security Group" created on the VPC for the workspace. Check the outbound rule, it's allowing custom, even with 0.0.0.0/0 still blocking. I changed to Anywhere-ipv4 and saved. It worked for me.